# need tool to identify most focussed image in a series

Tags: image-processing, photo

I have a situation where I am sent a series of photographs of hand-written documents (quite old, from 1850-s). Each photo is done just as you and I would photo a page from a book, so not a professional environment. So I have 3-4 images per page, all with a slightly different .. angle, lightning, etc. But the most tedious part that I hoped to automate was "to find which of the images in the set is best `focused` to be able to actually read the text"

So I've did some search here and on the Google, and people were suggesting to use such metrics as "deviation" and "enthropy". Now, I use `imagemagick` to get those values, and it seems as they are absolutely irrelevant for the task at hand, i.e. the images I would personally choose as best quality, have quite average values, for any given set of images & for both metrics (deviation/entropy), i.e. no min, no max, nothing. I am lost.

Maybe there's a (hint of) the solution, but I just can't google it properly ? Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: the metric I am after might be called "sharpness", or "perceptual sharpness index"

Comment: or "acutance": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acutance